# Is there an fsck command for checking the entire HDD?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fsck

This is probably a duplicate, but then please just link the post that answer my question.

Fsck seems to check partitions and file system, but is there a way to use a live CD, unmount (well, I guess the HDD wont be mounted anyway) the entire disc and have it checked for errors and bad sectors?

Would fsck -n /dec/sda work? sda is the name of the entire HDD in my case, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> fsck
>   Runs on partitions.

My recommendation is to run

parted /dev/sda 'print'

Then use that to run on each filesystem/partition based from the results.